# Fish counts and Poisson

Tags: poisson-distribution, goodness-of-fit, count-data, overdispersion

I am having troubles with fitting a Poisson distribution to my data, let me explain:

I have fish counts of different species from a closed list, at 5 sites, 2 different depths, and across 10 years. Each count was conducted 3 times, which I consider to be replicates. Fish were visually counted through diving survey transects.

I tried to test individual counts to determine whether they were sampled from a randomly distributed population of fish, and hence fit a Poisson distribution. To do so, I tried many different combinations, each time only selecting one year, one site and one depth. This leaves me with the three replicates of counts of each year, depth and site. And the counts are either all fish (if I aggregate species) or individual species (if I filter a specific species). In both cases, the counts should conform to a Poisson, since Poisson describes the probability of a given number of events to happen in a specific ammount of time with a specific frequency, no? However they are actually very far from that. Mean and variance differs by orders of magnitude, and even if I try the goodness of fit test with negative binomial, the result is absolutely negative. Do you think that 3 replicates is maybe not enough? Or am I missing some concept?

Comment: How were the fish caught? by trawl, by net, by line? ... If many were caught together, the catches are not independent, and in that case overdispersion, as you have seen, is to be expected. Can you please tell us some more detail and context?

Comment: "sampled from a randomly distributed population of fish" does not imply it will be well.fit by a Poisson distribution.  There is no reason that I can see why the counts should conform to a Poisson; you.might want to.revisit your assumptions in this regard, or at least make the more explicit in the question.